# Find the measure of angle E.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

http://static.k12.com/eli/bb/811/7537/0/2_36640_44211/7537/cfcbab7622b25115e3996826ebe54350776a6601/media/a0fb44a9ac3761c0d89bd1c3ffa513c508eb78bf/mediaasset_650483_1.gif

help please i still mix the formulas

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The inner angles of an $n$-gon add up to $(n-2)\pi$

From there, can you find $x$?

Comment: Ok so lets see if i got this.. N-2*pi

Comment: so it would be 7 * 3.14 = 21.98

Comment: but thats not an option the closet is 23

Comment: @Liz Well, that expression was in radians, if you want it in degrees, you need to use $180^\circ·(n-2)$

Comment: @Liz $$55x -5 = 180·7 \Rightarrow x = \frac{252}{11} \approx 22.90909...$$ So the angle at $E = \displaystyle\frac{1863}{11} \approx 169.36363636...$

Answer (score 0):

For an $n$-sided polygon, the sum of the interior angles is $180(n - 2)$. So I suggest that you try adding up all of those angle measures, setting it equal to $180(n - 2)$, and then solve for $x$. Afterwards, you'll just need to plug that value of $x$ into the angle measure of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the nonagon (the 9-sided polygon in the diagram) into triangles. If a triangle has $180^\circ$, a rectangle $360^\circ$, and a pentagon $540^\circ$, how many degrees would a nonagon have? are the angles measured in degrees or radians?

[image]